# Writes to cosmosdb never from pyspark runs forever / never succeeds nor fails

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using pyspark / databricks to E.T.L data from parquet files to CosmosDB (documentdb api).

Despite a first successful test with 5 rows of data, every following try to write data in cosmosdb just goes nowhere. Even with only one row, it just runs forever. When monitoring cosmosdb there is a regular, constant, flow of writing requests displayed in the "metrics" interface to the correct collection, but nothing is written.

In the stderr in spark there are errors stating "{"Errors":["The requested resource is no longer available at the server."]}" But it doesn't fail, it just loops.

I don't even know how to find the issue there.

config :

```
writeConfigUL = {
    "Endpoint" : "",
    "Masterkey" : "",
    "Database" : "Database",
    "Collection" : "Collection",
    "WritingBatchSize" : 500,
    "Upsert" : "true"
}
```

writing in "overwrite" mode

using  azure_cosmosdb_spark_2_3_0_2_11_1_2_7_uber.jar

Comment: After further experimentation, this behaviour is triggered by a nested partition key ex defining it as "/partition/key" while creating the collection and the dataset in spark having a "key" field in a "partition" struct.